# How to access an instance method of a class from the delegate which is in this class

Tags: c#, class, delegates

We have a class Command which takes an Action as a parameter in the constructor and we need to access some of the methods of the class Command from that Action. Is there a way how to achieve this?

```
public class Command
{
    private readonly Action _action;

    public Command(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        _action();
    }

    public void AnotherMethod()
    {
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    var command = new Command(() =>
                  {
                      // do something

                      // ?? how to access and call 
                      // command.AnotherMethod(); ??

                      // do something else
                   });
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Command
{
    private readonly Action<Command> _action;

    public Command(Action<Command> action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        _action(this);
    }

    public void AnotherMethod()
    {
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    var command = new Command(cmd => cmd.AnotherMethod() );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Action<T>` and pass the object into itself.. like this:

```
public class Command {
    private readonly Action<Command> _action;

    public Command(Action<Command> action) {
        _action = action;
    }

    public void Execute() {
        _action(this);
    }

    public void AnotherMethod() {
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var command = new Command(x => {
    x.AnotherMethod();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Action where T is your Command class.

```
public class Command
{
    private readonly Action<Command> _action;

    public Command(Action<Command> action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        _action(this);
    }

    public void AnotherMethod()
    {
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    var command = new Command(command =>
                  {
                      // do something

                      // ?? how to access and call 
                      // command.AnotherMethod(); ??

                      // do something else
                   });
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the Action delegate a parameter when you declare it: `Action<Command>`

You then call it as `action(this)` from within your Command. When passing your Action you use `(command) => command.AnotherMethod()`